# Alert "Completed" everytime after specific action applied in photoshop

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe, extendscript, photoshop-script

I want to get a Javascript alert when a user in photoshop apply a action by click.
check this [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/1xdbn81) .Here, When user click on gray color action will be applied after that it should give a alert that completed.

i tried below this code, but its not working. Looking forward your help.

```js
app.actions["actionName"].onComplete(function(){ alert('action name - completed') })
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a function that will call the action. In my example, I've got an action that flattens all the layers. Just replace the name of the action and it's action set with the one you want ("Check new with trim").

```
// Play action
// replace these parameters with your own
play_action("Flatten layers", "My Favourite Actions");

function play_action(actName, actSet)
{
    // =======================================================
    var idPly = charIDToTypeID( "Ply " );
    var desc1784 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref572 = new ActionReference();
    var idActn = charIDToTypeID( "Actn" );
    ref572.putName( idActn, actName ); // Action name
    var idASet = charIDToTypeID( "ASet" );
    ref572.putName( idASet, actSet ); // Action set name
    desc1784.putReference( idnull, ref572 );
    executeAction( idPly, desc1784, DialogModes.NO );

    alert("action " + actName + " complete.")
}
```

Comment: I don't want to play action by script. Action will be play from Photoshop, just want to give alert after play it manually from photoshop.

like If(actionClicked == true) { alert('whatever')}

Comment: You gotta remember Photoshop uses javascript but isn't a web application; it's functionality is limited. You might however, be able to do what you want with the **Scripts Event Manager**.

Comment: I tried a lot to find that , do have that keyword where i can set the conditon and get the alert ?it would be great if you could help me to give any source or had already the solution

Comment: Save you alert as action. Go to the events manager, in Photoshop Event: choose Add An Event. Put something the the title but put "Ply " - P l y <space> without quotes in the Descriptive Label. Choose your Action that plays the alert. And finally press the Add button to save it.

Comment: Awesome Ghoul Fool. Its working nicely. But the problem its playing with all action. anyway to give specific action name on that EVENT??

Comment: Look [here](https://www.tranberry.com/photoshop/photoshop/PhotoshopUseMagScriptEvents.pdf) for more info